# FastAPI & sqlAlchemy: TypeError: Array() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sequence'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

When making an sqlAlchemy model for an array, give below

```
class Post(base):
 __tablename__ = "posts"
   answer = column(Array[string],nullable=false)
```

sqlAlchemy throws fllowing error,

```
TypeError: Array() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sequence'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Array(string)`? Where did you import `Array` from?

Comment: from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

Comment: Then it should be `Array(String)`, not `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not defining the table definition correctly. See the sample table definition.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import String, Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

Base = declarative_base()

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    answer = Column(ARRAY(String))
```

References:

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html